# Jquery custom file input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This jquery plugin allows you to turn any element into a file input element. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/custom-file

But to actually upload the file, the only  documentation i could found is this:

> To upload the chosen file to a server you should then attach the input element to a form element

how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to create an html form and append the input to the form, and if you need to submit, you can do it via a submit button or via $.submit

```
    # from http://www.daimi.au.dk/~u061768/file-input.html
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('button').button().add('#foo, a').file().choose(function(e, input) {
        $(input).appendTo('#TheForm').
                         attr('name', 'a-name').
                         attr('id', 'an-id');
    });


});
    </script>
    ...
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="TheForm" action="/path/in/your/server/">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
```

Anyway this is not the best plugin for submiting the files via ajax.

Comment: I don't need ajax upload, i just need to use a custom element as a file upload field in my form. do you have any plugins to recommend?

Comment: but what do you need exaclty?

Comment: May be the plugin you are using is what you need, see this code http://jsfiddle.net/m7Rj8/

Comment: oh, that's great, thanks. it's exactly what i need. But it seems the input is not submitting with the form. the server is not getting the file.. do you know how to tell the input it's part of that form and give the field a name?

Answer (score 0):

The uploading itself is not of the scope of this plugin. You should see this with your server side technology.

Comment: Got that. but all this plugin does is bring up a file chooser and stores the file chosen in a variable. how to insert that variable in the form and have it submitted server side?